# How to merge two arrays into a respective 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

So I have two arrays:

```
        String movieList[] = {
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E"
    };

    int gross[] = {
            623,
            333,
            516,
            389,
            448
    };
```

So I have seen questions combining two arrays but how do I do it by it's respective index?

for example:

I am trying to make this:

```
result[][] = {{"A",1},{"B",2},{"C",3}...};
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions!!

Comment: Try adding code of your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: `String` and `int`? What kind of array do you think you'll have? `Object`? What is the use case? `Map` might be something you are looking for.

Comment: Your `result` array, as you've described it, is not two dimensional, it's one dimensional.  Also, it appears that you want JSON output.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

***You are trying to merge two different data types into one.***

You can either:

- Convert the int array into String
- Create a class and encapsulate the String object and the     int value inside one object.

*You need to understand the flaw in what you are trying to do!*

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
String movieList[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
int gross[] = { 623, 333, 516, 389, 448 };
Object obj[][] = new Object[movieList.length][2];
for (int i = 0; i < movieList.length; i++) {
    obj[i][0] = movieList[i];
    obj[i][1] = gross[i];
}
```

Comment: this is literally what the OP asked for, but you might want to point out what a poor design choice this is, and suggest something more idiomatic.

Comment: @PatrickParker I can see not many people are happy about a design like this with objects.. why is that?

Comment: @JCr8 java is primarily an Object Oriented language, so you should consider the proper classes to be used, rather than stuffing all your data into generic arrays. Consider: code clarity, type safety, code maintainability.  Your design gets an F for all of these.

Comment: Patrick Parker - You are technically correct that generic arrays are not a good idea. But SO is a teaching site, so there is no need for harsh impoliteness.  Your last comment would have gotten a B+ if you would have left off your last sentence.

Answer (score 1):

One option for your exact situation would be to build a hashmap of movie keys and gross values.  Then, convert that map to a JSON string using a library such as Jackson:

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i < movieList.length; ++i) {
    map.put(movieList[i], String.valueOf(gross[i]));
}

String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(map);
System.out.println(json);
```

Comment: Although the question looks like it demands JSON I think this is not helpful. The question has an array initializer, there is no JSON-string there.

Comment: @leoderprofi I'm waiting for feedback from the OP, then I will delete if appropriate.

Comment: I am confused as well ;)